# HighCharts - show last labels in xAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can I force to show last labels in xAxis? I tried to use showLastLabel: true. But as you see doesn't really work.

See example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/X3jPh/770/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In addition to the `showLastLabel` property, you may need to add the `endOnTick` flag to your example. For example:

```
//...

xAxis: [{
    type: 'datetime',
    showLastLabel: true,
    endOnTick: true
},

//...
```

Comment: I had same issue and this solution is working good. Is it possible to set the last X-axis value to exact custom value? for example, if I am showing loan period on x-axis, and user enters 13, then how can I show 13 as last value?

Answer (score 0):

Use tickPositions Array:(number) to specifically identify which indices you want displayed on your xAxis.

Comment: It would be great if you could add a code example to demonstrate your idea. Without it, this is really more of a comment than an answer and may be deleted during review.