# How do I put the last label highcharts?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, highcharts

How to place a mark in the latest Highcharts? even if there is no place
[image]

The graph shows that there is still more data

Comment: please provide code.

Comment: You may want to see this question, which talks about `endOnTick` and `showLastLabel`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400573/highcharts-show-last-labels-in-xaxis As @SagarR noted, if you could please provide some code to review, that would help to see whether these attributes would help you. Thanks!

Comment: Set the endOnTick and maxPadding as 0. http://jsfiddle.net/dctw1L1a/ If it will not solve the issue, update my code with yours. Then I will be able to find a better solution.